# Escape PHP Switch Variable String

Tags: php, escaping, switch-statement, case

In PHP, we can escape to HTML in a switch statement like this:

```
<?php
    switch($example) {
        case 'caseone': { ?> <p>Case one</p> <?php } break;
        case 'casetwo': { ?> <p>Case two</p> <?php } break;
    }
?>
```

Also, we can set variables:

```
<?php
    switch($example) {
        case 'caseone': $text = 'Case one'; break;
        case 'casetwo': $text = 'Case two'; break;
    }
?>
```

But how can we escape the variable string like in this pseudo code?

```
<?php
    switch($example) {
        case 'caseone': $text = { ?> Case one <?php } break;
        case 'casetwo': $text = { ?> Case two <?php } break;
    }
?>
```

I'd like to output a lot of HTML this way, but I don't want to echo it in the switch
because I have to build a string later containing the $text variable and more.

I might be a bit stupid here.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually really simple.  You're thing about it wrong.  Your second example was what you actually need.  You don't need to "escape" to HTML in order to build up strings (especially if you want to `echo` them later).  If you do want to remove any chance of XSS attacks, you can use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to escape the HTML.

```
<?php
    switch($example) {
        case 'caseone': $text = "HTML string here"; break;
        case 'casetwo': $text = "Other HTML string here"; break;
    }
echo $text;
?>
```

Comment: That was already there, see the 2nd example, actually he has an answer in his question, there's nothing to escape in here

Comment: That did it. Thanks! Seems obvious now. But can I escape it if I want? My text-editor does not syntax highlight content in strings.

Comment: @bchr Glad to help (don't forget to upvote/accept!).  As far as I know, you can't "escape" it in this fashion.  You may want to look at upgrading to an IDE.

Comment: @SomeKittens I still need a few points to upvote but I accepted it. I use Notepad++ on Windows and love it's lightweight but yes, maybe I should.

Comment: NP++ is an excellent editor, except for a few small flaws like the one you discovered.

Comment: @SomeKittens I got enough points to upvote. Thanks again and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question, you want to be able to assign a large block of text, possibly containing HTML, to a variable.  The best way to do this is with the heredoc syntax like this:

```
<?php
switch($example) {
    case 'caseone':
        $text = <<<EOT
Case one 
Some <a href="link">HTML</a>
EOT;
        break;
    case 'casetwo':
        $text = <<<EOT
Case two 
Some other <a href="link2">HTML</a>
EOT;
        break;
}
?>
```

With the heredoc syntax, you don't need to escape anything; Everything between the opening and closing tags are treated as literals so you can easily assign text with single and double quotes and use interpolation.